# Indicating the current date in date picker of a form in html 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How could I indicate current date as a placeholder in a form in html 5 using following code.

```
Date: <input type="date" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" name="date" />
```

Comment: The only accurate way to do that would be on the serverside, otherwise you'd have to rely on the time and date on the users computer.

Comment: As a sidenote, the placeholder isn't visible in a date input on most browsers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the date inputs value to the current date, you can do something like this:

```
var d = new Date(),
    s = d.getFullYear() + '-' + (d.getMonth()+1) + '-' + d.getDate()

document.getElementsByName('date')[0].value = s;
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/M5t3G/)

Comment: How does this not answer the question? An input with a date type has no placeholder to change in most browsers, so you change the value, just like my answer above does, and that sets the value of the input to the current date, it's exactly like your edited answer (which you edited after I posted mine), but with less jQuery ?